# Boost.asio and asynchronous chain, unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio, asyncsocket

I am not deeply familiar with async programming and I have a question.

My question is the following. Given the echo_server example here for C++11 in boost.asio: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/spawn/echo_server.cpp

I would like to know if the `std::make_shared<session>` can be replaced in C++14 with a `std::unique_ptr<session>`in C++14, avoiding the overhead of reference count.

I am not sure since we have `shared_from_this()` but not something like `unique_from_this()`, so how can I access the `unique_ptr<session>` from inside `this`?.

Comment: You are aware the overhead is a single pointer of extra memory per instance and a reference count bump on shared ptr creation and deletion -- otherwise it's exactly the same as a normal pointer.  Also it's not clear which shared_ptr you're referring to as there are multiple in that example.

Comment: The concept of a "unique_from_this" doesn't even make sense.   You can't simply create a unique pointer to a memory address arbitrarily, as you'd have a race condition as to who cleaned up the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the use of shared_ptr in `asio` programming is idiomatic.

The idea is that the number of outstanding handlers is matched by the shared-count of the object initiating the async operations. This is achieved by binding a copy of the `shared_ptr` managing the object into the handler function objects.

The c++11/14 way would be to replace the `boost::shared_ptr` with `std::shared_ptr` (`std::bind`, lambdas, etc also work perfectly well with asio).

Update, now that I fully understand the question:

In the example you linked, I take it that you're referring to the shared_ptr called self which is created in the method go() ? You could write it without the shared_ptr if you wanted. You'd have to put a delete this as the last line of go(). You'd also have to remember to catch any exceptions to ensure this code path was taken. A unique_ptr could be set up to do this of course, but then you've got a lifetime management issue between the construction of the session and the successful creation of the adopting unique_ptr. shared_ptr eases the management burden for the cost of one atomic inc...

In which case the answer is strictly "yes", but imho I'll-advised as it's more brittle.

Comment: As I understand it, your session object will go through a pipeline of handlers, one at a time. The state of your session is never shared. Why a unique_ptr would not make sense? The point is that when the latest handler is finished, the memory will be released. Does this hold true?

Comment: Latest or last? If there are any outstanding handlers which involve the session they will all eventually fire (even if cancelled as a result of destroying the socket). You could keep a manual count of outstanding handlers and delete your session when it reaches zero, but why? The shared_ptr does exactly this with almost no overhead.

Comment: If there is a session there is still work in asio's loop. It will not finish. So, if I am not wrong, what will happen is the following: if you use unique_ptr's for each of the sessions, only when there is no more work, the loop will finish. I agree the overhead may be low, this is more a theory question :)

Comment: In the example you linked, I take it that you're referring to the shared_ptr called self which is created in the method go() ? You could write it without the shared_ptr if you wanted. You'd have to put a `delete this` as the last line of `go()`. You'd also have to remember to catch any exceptions to ensure this code path was taken. A unique_ptr could be set up to do this of course, but then you've got a lifetime management issue between the construction of the session and the successful creation of the adopting unique_ptr. shared_ptr eases the management burden for the cost of one atomic inc..

Comment: @GermánDiago ...in which case when I said, "no" I meant "yes" :)

Comment: I see. if you document that last comment in your reply I can close as solved :) That answers my question.

Comment: _"If there is a session there is still work in asio's loop"_ - that's just chicken and egg. It's not a truth in any sense. It _is_ true when the session disappears with the last pending operation (but that's circular reasoning).

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand it, your session object will go through a pipeline of handlers, one at a time. The state of your session is never shared. Why a unique_ptr would not make sense? The point is that when the latest handler is finished, the memory will be released. Does this hold true?

Yes, this is the trick. The library has been designed around copyable completion handlers.

If you worry about overhead, indeed avoid shared_ptr.

In that case, just carry a reference to some state with  externally controlled lifetime. Just make sure it stays alive (just as you do with the io_service object itself).

Comment: I understand this, but that does not reply my original question, which is: can I use a unique_ptr and do a unique_pr that will be automatically carried until the session itself dies?

Comment: If you understood it, why [did you ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109220/boost-asio-and-asynchronous-chain-unique-ptr/37109892?noredirect=1#comment61761197_37109300)? Also, I don't know how to answer more clearly. [Is `std::unique_ptr` copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)? If not, then using it in completion handlers directly is not possible, and going to be a kludge at best when "papered-over" with indirection. My advice is in my answer.

Comment: In C++14 you can capture [my_ptr=move(my_ptr)] but I wondered if there are any remaining problems. Most concerned about "`unique_from_this()`" or similar so I wondered if this is genuinely possible to achieve: replace by unique_ptr and have something similar.

Comment: You can, but that does not make the result copyable. As others have mentioned "unique_from_this" makes zero sense. My advice on "something similar" has been in the answer from the get-go. `delete this` is one way to hack that result. I consider that a code smell, but it might be close to your mental model of things.