# Boost ASIO socket consumes file descriptors never cleared

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using Boost ASIO sockets for communicating with some remote devices under linux, but i have a problem when the endpoint is not reachable. First of all, here's the portion of code that shows this issue:

```
try {
   if(mysocket == NULL)
   {
      mysocket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service);
   }
   mysocket->connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.0.12"), 1));
   printf("connected\n");
   return 0;
}
catch (std::exception &e)
{
   boost::system::error_code ec;
   mysocket->close(ec);
   delete mysocket;
   mysocket = NULL;
   printf("not connected %s\n", e.what());
}
```

By using this piece of code inside my class I get an increasing number of file descriptors of type eventfd, until all the available fds are used and the application crashes. Is there any problem with the code above? Why boost is not closing the file descriptors? I even delete the socket! Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I am leaking resources" combined with manual resource management should raise immediate suspicion. Switching to RAII'd resources will likely make the error go away.

Comment: I do not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others said, just don't write `new` and `delete`, and you know you didn't mess it up yourself.

In particular your misguided

```
mysocket->close(ec);
```

will throw because the socket isn't open in the first place, so you never reached `delete`.

However, `mysocket` can be automatically destructed at the end of scope:
The entire code can be simplified to:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    ba::io_context io_service;
    try {
        tcp::socket mysocket(io_service);
        mysocket.connect({ba::ip::address::from_string("192.168.0.12"), 1});
        std::cout << "Connected to " << mysocket.remote_endpoint() << "\n";
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        std::cout << "System error: " << se.code().message() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @DeepakAnmol Can you just say what the issue is? Because you can trust I read it multiple times. I explicitly explain why you are NOT deleting the socket.

Comment: Whenever we are executing this line

`mysocket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service);`

at that time **eventfd, eventpoll & timerfd** are created as file descriptors. And when we called `mysocket->connect......` then TCP connection is made. When whole execution is done then only TCP Connection file descriptor is close **NOT the eventfd, eventpoll & timerfd** and in between of the the program we are getting 'To Many Files Open' because File Descriptors defined count is greater.

Comment: Are you also dynamically allocating the `io_service`? I mean, if you mismanaged the resources in the snippet you show (like I explained) it's not impossible that you have similar problems elsewhere. I'd really like to help more, but until you either post more code or rewrite your code to not use manual memory management and only use exception-safe resource acquisition instead, I won't be able to say more.

Comment: Did you understand how the code you showed is flawed? Especially since you say _"but i have a problem when the endpoint is not reachable"_ which by definition means that the `delete` will not be reached.

Comment: endpoint not reachable (endpoint used in mysocket->connect( .... ), means TCP server is not running, and we are not able to connect but we have object of mysocket and we can also close/delete it.

Comment: are you getting my point for eventfd, eventpoll & timerfd file descriptors ?

Comment: This is just the demo application I have given, this is not the actual code.

Comment: Yes I got the point about eventfd, eventpoll, timerfd. This is why I asked about the other code (_"Are you also dynamically allocating the io_service?_")

Comment: yes I am using dynamic, I also have option to use io_context

Comment: You're most likely also not managing those dynamic allocations in an exception safe fashion.

Comment: You can see [a ton of my examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+%5Bboost-asio%5D+io_service+socket+connect): you'll see that I rarely  need dynamic allocation (certainly not for the `io_service` e.g.). Asio does quite strongly pattern for `shared_ptr` though (keeping buffers and similar alive during asynchronous operations, but ONLY for asynchronous operations). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109220/boost-asio-and-asynchronous-chain-unique-ptr/37109892#37109892)

Comment: Your idea works well. As IO Service is changed with IO Context. I have used that now  IO Context but as a shared pointer and this is now globally defined. Last time we were having two instances.